# Changing base class for WPF page code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple class called CustomPage which inherits from Window:

```
public class CustomPage : Window 
{
    public string PageProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I want my MainWindow codebehind to inherit from CustomPage as follows:

```
public partial class MainWindow : CustomPage
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Partial declarations of 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow' must not specify different base classes
```

I can set x:Class to "WpfApplication1.CustomPage" in MainWindow.xaml, but then it appears I don't have access to the UI elements defined in MainWindow.xaml...

Comment: You should see this article: [Creating a Base Window Class in WPF](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/11/02/creating-a-base-window-class-in-wpf.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public partial class MainWindow 
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}

public class CustomPage : Window
{
    public string PageProperty { get; set; }
}

<myWindow:CustomPage x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:myWindow="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800">
<Grid>
</Grid>
</myWindow:CustomPage>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: This won't work unless you inherit `MainWindow` from `CustomPage` in code behind as well.

Comment: xaml is ultimately converted into partial class with the same name as its code behind thats why code behind class is always partial, so it does'nt matter

Comment: Oh yeah. I somehow missed it. +1 for it. :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to update your xaml like this -

```
<local:CustomPage x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
</local:CustomPage>
```

Here, `local` is your namespace where `CustomPage` and `MainWindow` resides.

As the error suggested, you can't declare different base classes for partial declaration of class. So, in XAML too, you need to use the `CustomPage` instead of WPF `Window`